# How do I create a plain table with multiple table cells, each linking to their own push segue?

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

At the moment, following the tutorials, they all seem to use an array to display the table. However, my app requires a table that doesn't really change, it's sort of like a settings page. Unfortunately, I can't make all of the cells link to different push segues, as I only have one Identifier for all of my cells. How do I go about this? All I want is a table 6 cells that never change, each linking to their own push segue, similar to a settings page. dequeuereusable cell with identifier seems to work only with the array method of creating the tables.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create all the needed segue in the storyboard between the tableViewController and all the other view controllers,
2. assign to each segues a name/identifier
3. Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableviewDidSelectCellAtIndePath` (remember to set the tableview delegate)
4. and there call the wanted `performSegueWithIdentifier` based on the indexpath of the cell and the given name/identifier of the segue